# Can a model return its own View?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm developing a application where a list has to display different implementations of the same interface (for example, TextImplementation, VideoImplementation, AudioImplementation e.t.c). In this case, would it be good design to have the model return its view?

Here is an example of some code that demonstrates what I have in mind.
Note that the Model doesn't actually design the view, it merely returns an instance of it.

```
public interface Impl{
    public Object getQuestion();
    public String getAnswer();
    public View getListCellView();
}

public class AudioImpl implements Impl{

    private File audioFile;
    private String answer;

    public Audio getQuestion(){

        Audio a = Audio.fromFile(audioFile);
        return a;

    }

    public String getAnswer(){

        return answer;

    }

    public View getListCellView(){

        return new AudioListCellView(audioFile);
    }
}

public class AudioListCellView extends View{

    private File file;

    public AudioListCellView(File audioFile){

        this.file  = audioFile;

    }

    public View createView(){

        AudioPlayer ap = new AudioPlayer();
        ap.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(ClickEvent e){

                play(this.file);

            }

        });

        this.addView(ap,Layout.CENTER);

    }

}
```

The reason I'm considering this design is because when rendering the list items, I can simply write something like this:

```
class QuestionsListView extends ListView{

    private Collection<Impl> list;

    public View getCellView(int position){

        Impl anImpl = list.get(position);
        return anImpl.getListCellView();
    }

}
```

Are there downsides to this design? How can it be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Are there downsides to this design?

Yeah.

The core idea of MVC-like patterns is Separation of Concerns, that implies that each triad can be used separately. By definition, a view can only access model's state. But you if you return a view's instance from a model, then you break the core principle of MVC. Model's layer should never know if there's a thing called view.

What you do in view, surely belongs to View's layer (which usually consists of UI's logic and template).

So, to answer your question:

Can a model return its own View? Yes, you can do that, but that's no longer MVC. Since model is now aware of view and knows how to build it.

In your case, the best option would be creating a special factory for views, which can build their instances.

So keep in mind, as long as:

- A model is layer and has no knowledge of Views and Controllers
- A view consists of UI's logic and template, and can access a model directly
- A controller can alter either view's or model's state

You can call that implementation MVC. Otherwise, just implement what works best for you, but don't call that MVC.

Comment: A Factory was an alternative I had in mind but I was kinda hoping to avoid that `if(anImpl instanceof VideoImpl){}` thing

Comment: You can also consider using `Adapter` pattern then. There you might have several View adapters (like AudioImpl) and then inject them on demand

Comment: Maybe you should consider using the Composite View pattern. Your AudioList class should not be holding an AudioImpl collection, but an AudioView collection.